# How to access the selected image from an ImageRow in Eureka?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eureka-forms

How do you access the image selected by an ImageRow in Eureka?

```
form = Section()
            <<< ImageRow("Pic"){
                $0.title = "Picture"
            }.cellSetup { cell, row in

                if let picPath = NSURL(string: _user.pic!),
                    data = NSData(contentsOfURL: picPath) {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
```

For text fields, I'm doing this to get the form value:

```
let values = form.values()
if values["Name"]! != nil {
   name = values["Name"] as! String
}
```

Trying to figure out how I can get the value for image rows. I need to upload the selected image to my server.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

```
let picture = values["Pic"] as? UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to show a placeholder when there is no image and remove the placeholder when an image is selected, this is how I do it

```
<<< ImageRow(FormItems.imageEntryOne) { row in
row.title = "Image #1"
row.noValueDisplayText = "Select"
row.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum]
row.clearAction = .yes(style: .destructive)
}
.cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
    cell.accessoryView?.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    cell.accessoryView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
}).onChange({ (row) in
    row.noValueDisplayText = row.value == nil ? "Select" : ""
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow this , swift 4.x

```
let imageRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "ImageRow") as? ImageRow
```

now you can access imageRow.value? which returns UIImage, 
so you can use this

```
guard let imageValue = imageRow?.value else{return}
```

if you want to upload it to server , simply convert the image to NSdata

```
let selectedImage = NSData()
selectedImage = imageRow?.value?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)
```